# Laravel Collective - Model binding issue for non eloquent table names

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I have a User model that **has** to have a table named admin_users, which is already stipulated in the model (`protected $table = 'admin_users';`)

I am using Laravel Collective form as follows:

`{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}`

My validation as follows:

```
  $rules = array(
        'first_name'    => 'required',
        'last_name'     => 'required',
        'email'         => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
        'country_id'    => 'required|numeric',
        'user_status'   => 'required'
    );
```

The only reason I am using Laravel Collective `FORM::model` for the ease of getting the request input back when validation fails:

(`return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all())`

On validation success though I am getting:

`` SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = jocelyn33@example.com) ``

The weird thing is that it's not taking the table from User class table.

My question is if there is a way to have `FORM::model` get `admin_users` table name rather than `users`, **and** if I decide to let go of `FORM::model` and use `FORM::open`, would I still be able to get back request inputs of a failed validation?

Comment: I'm not sure about the first part of your question but getting the old input values is easy with the helper function `old('field_name')` - see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-old

Comment: do you have the `unique` rule in your validation? are you giving it the correct table?

Comment: Please post the part of your view where you use `Form::model()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir -added in question

Comment: @lagbox -I added my validation rules in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation rules are defining what table to use for a unique check:

```
'email'         => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
```

`unique:users` is telling the unique rule to use the `users` table.

`unique:table,column,except,idColumn` - 
[Laravel Docs 5.6 - Validation - Unique Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: just add the idColumn ($id) to your answer, and thanks.